# Time Domain Measurements with Vector Analyzer

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission-line, electromagnetic, microwave, vna

In my university I have done some time domain measurements with a VNA (by using the transform operation of the instrument). Precisely, I have selected the measurement of the real part of S11 while leaving port 1 open (so port 1 of the device is connected to a floating coaxial cable), and I selected the Step Response Mode.

The result of my measurement is this one (a step signal has been sent by the VNA, and a step signal I have obtained for the real part of S11)::

[image]

Now I have 3 questions:

1) **What is exactly S11 measured by the instrument in that situation?** During the lecture I have been told it is the reflection coefficient of the DUT - which in this case is a floating coaxial cable - , but in theory S11 coincides with the input reflection coefficient only if the other port is matched (and in this case it is open). So what does it represent?

2) In that situation the input reflection coefficient of the floating coaxial cable shoud have absolute value equal to 1 (total reflection), and real and imaginary part function of the position on the coaxial cable (and so of time of moving along it). My question is: **why is the real part of S11 a step, like the signal sent by the VNA during the analysis?**

3) S11 depends on t with a precise mathematical relationship. **Why does its curve depend on the mode we select on the instrument (low pass step/low pass pulse)?**

Comment: S11 is always the input reflection coefficitn of the device under test. Your unterminated coax line, and your coax terminated line, are two different devices. Why transform only the real part of S11? Take data, throw away half the data, expect sense after transforming what's left? VNA doesn't send a step during analysis, a TDR does. A VNA sends a sequence of sines, whose transform is a bandpass impulse. Step versus pulse involves an integration, of course the results are different.

Comment: Regarding S11... How can the device measure it, if the line is not closed on a matched load (by its definition, S11 is Vreflected/Vincident when other ports are matched)?

Comment: When a VNA is connected to a one-port black-box component, and measures S11, it measures the returned wave divided by the incident wave at that port. If the component is a terminated line, it measures a combination of the line's ideal return loss and the termination's return loss, which is a reasonable approximation to the line's ideal return loss if the termination is good. If the component is an unterminated line, it measures a combination of the line's return loss and the far open circuit, which is nothing like the line's ideal return loss.

Comment: To measure the line's ideal return loss, it either needs to be terminated in a sliding load, or a TDR method used to isolated the initial reflection from the far reflection.